# possibility of paying fees by bitcoins in IEEE transactions?

Tags: ieee, fees

Is it possible to pay IEEE transaction fees/charges by bitcoins?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think so. At least for the IEEE Transactions I know of, payments are managed by RightsLink, a company external to IEEE. In the help center of this company, you can find information on how to pay:

[How do I complete the RightsLink order? How can I pay the charges due?](https://copyright.secure.force.com/kb/articles/Knowledge/How-do-I-complete-the-RightsLink-order-How-can-I-pay-the-charges-due/?l=en_US&c=CCC_FAQ%3APublishers_RightsLink_Author&hc=1&fs=Search&pn=1)

It is there written that (bold mine)

> Select your preferred payment option (**invoice or credit card**)

and

> If you submit your order with the “invoice” payment method, you can pay that invoice later using a **credit card, wire transfer, or check**.

They want the good ol' dirty money!